# Bluetooth Support for Yoga 11s in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: bluetooth, 14.04, lenovo, ideapad

I recently installed 14.04 LTS on my lenovo yoga 11s. I was wondering if there is/will be bluetooth support on this machine. As it stands, the bluetooth tab in the system settings shows the swtich, which can be toggled to show on, but no bluetooth activity is apparent. When you close the tab and reopen it, the switch is toggled back to off.

Thanks for any support

Comment: Bluethooth doesn't work well on many machines. You would probably get better support by using a third party app like blueman. `sudo apt-get install blueman`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I've installed blueman bluez bluewho etc., if it had blue in the name I probably installed it. Still no devices detected, no bluetooth activation apparent. Any ideas?

Comment: You tried activating bluetooth from *within* the blueman app?

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything, neither device>activate nor adapter>activate

Comment: Can you figure out what Bluetooth chip you have? Edit the output of `lspci` into your question please.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Lenovo Ideapad 710.

A **lsusb** return

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
**Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc.** 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 03f0:1024 Hewlett-Packard Smart Card Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 5986:0295 Acer, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0461:4d51 Primax Electronics, Ltd 0Y357C PMX-MMOCZUL (B) [Dell Laser Mouse]
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Goggling the USB ID's you can find which one is the Bluetooth device in my case 0cf3:3004 Atheros is in fact the Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth device.

Then if you perform a **dmesg output** I could find two lines saying

[   13.946058] Bluetooth: **Patch file not found ar3k/AthrBT_0x01020200.dfu**
[   13.946058] Bluetooth: Loading patch file failed

Goggling again **AthrBT_0x01020200.dfu** the problem is solved installing the firmwares package **linux-firmware**

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

which install the firmware file /lib/firmware/ar3k/AthrBT_0x01020200.dfu.

That solve the problem.

Comment: @GnomGnom Did this resolve your bluetooth needs?